# Weird shadows in android EditViews and Autocomplete TextViews

Tags: android, android-studio, uiview, android-gradle-plugin

If someone can help me get rid of this shadows appearing in editviews and autocomplete textviews I'll appreciate. I have created a simple project(LoginActivity) in android studio 2.2 Preview 3, and the EditView appear with gray shadows at run time
[image]

Below is my Module: app for gradule
[image]

Comment: those are not shadows, thats an image that was not rendered properly, I believe its a bug in the latest support library

Comment: @tyczj so do i downgrade or what?!!

Comment: well if you downgrade then you also have to downgrade your targetsdk since those have to match

Comment: I think its been fixed with support v 24.1.0 repo but now `AppbarLayout` wont show application title on titlebar..